# How do I get the Python base environment running for Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, environment

I am new to using multiple Python environments and for some reason the base environment in my system just will not work for Jupyter notebooks. When I try to open a notebook from the base environment, I am getting the error phrase '500: Internal Server Error'. However, I am able to get notebooks opened if I create a new environment but even after installing the necessary modules, Python does not seem to recognise them. Another issue is that, once I terminate a session in the newly created environment, it too stops working giving the error phrase '500: Internal Server Error'. Basically, I am having to create environments again and again since the base environment itself is dysfunctional yet all the environments break upon termination.

I have also noted that '!python --version' and 'sys.version' returns two different values despite correct activation of the required environment (which is not the base environment) and opening a notebook from the activated environment.

Any solution for this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that `!python --version` calls the system's version of python, while `sys.version` in Jupyter will return info on the Jupyter kernel it's running in.

Comment: Thank you! Isn't it the other way round?

Comment: The `!` before `!python` can essentially be read as "execute shell command"